# Need Help saving user input

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

```js
activated = false
function getName() {
  name = document.getElementById("enter").value;
  localStorage.setItem("names", name)
  activated = true
}

if (activated == true) {
  document.getElementById("enter-name").style.display = 'none';

}
```

I'm trying to build a Chrome ‘new tab’ extension, and I'm trying to make the user input their name into a form, and there will be a greeting (e.g. `'Good Afternoon' + name`) after a button next to the input field is clicked, using an `onclick` event which executes the function above.

But when I try my code it doesn’t work (the form does not disappear), and I do not know how to make the form appear only the first time its being loaded, and not after other reloads.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add your code as it is important for us to start helping you

Comment: I did, its in the picture @finnmglas. please look for the "1" with the blue underline in the beginning of the paragraph. I have attached a pic of my code there

Comment: It is not recommended to add the images , instead you should add code in the question using {} option

Comment: Post it as actual code - have a look at this [meme](https://preview.redd.it/tz6njzcf67y01.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=6ffa4ada80daf3f63022edb3008b77e53c744e50) ^^

Comment: Please review [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Questions must ***also* include the relevant code in the question itself**, not as images or solely in external links. See how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help.

Comment: @finnmglas   sorry , I have already pasted the code. I had trouble formatting the code before, and was just a bit lazy in general.

Comment: Warning:  Developing Chrome extensions is super hard, even for someone otherwise skilled at web development.